# How to send file to server side from client side using ajax without using handler?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have sent file to handler page using ajax.but now i am trying to send file to webmethod using ajax.i cant able to get the file.i have put my sample code below please give me any idea.
This is my javacript code

```
 <input type="file" id="MsoBill"   class="MsoReqdit upload">

    var Frmdata = new FormData();
    var Files = $("#MsoBill").get(0).files;
    Frmdata.append("test", Files[0])


  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'MyForm.aspx/testAjax',
        data: '{test:' + Frmdata + '}',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
        processData:false,
        success: function (res) { debugger; alert(res); },
        failure: function (result) {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
```

My server side code

```
[WebMethod]
public static int testAjax(Object test)
{

        return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should receive (or cast) the test object to a HttpPostedFileBase, then do

```
 MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
 test.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
 byte[] data = target.ToArray(); //here are the bytes
```

then simply save the file or do what you need:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("path",bytes);
```

or

```
test.SaveAs("path");
```

As you need